# AWS Cloudfront API works on browser but 403 error from .net HttpClient

Tags: c#, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudfront, dotnet-httpclient

I try to access an API from browswer, it returns data properly.

Below is the output of Chrome Dev Tools - Network Tab

```
GET /xxxxxxx/api/xxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxxxx?referencenumber=AVXD13198802469/1 HTTP/1.1
Host: xxxx.xxxxxxx.xxx
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
sec-ch-ua: " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="96", "Google Chrome";v="96"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.45 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
Sec-Fetch-Site: none
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
Sec-Fetch-Dest: document
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-GB,en;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,hi;q=0.7,te;q=0.6
Cookie: _ga=GA1.2.324340773.1637687185; _hjSessionUser_1162220=eyJpZCI6IjVjN2Q4ZjZiLTE3NGYtNWRlOS1iN2ZjLWFhMzU3NGJjYmFjNSIsImNyZWF0ZWQiOjE2Mzc2ODcxODUzMzYsImV4aXN0aW5nIjpmYWxzZX0=; OptanonAlertBoxClosed=2021-11-23T17:06:55.324Z; OptanonConsent=isGpcEnabled=0&datestamp=Tue+Nov+23+2021+22%3A37%3A28+GMT%2B0530+(India+Standard+Time)&version=6.18.0&isIABGlobal=false&hosts=&consentId=e2272ab8-8e01-4859-902a-e8e84fbe8b35&interactionCount=1&landingPath=NotLandingPage&groups=C0001%3A1%2CC0003%3A1%2CC0002%3A1%2CC0004%3A1&geolocation=%3B&AwaitingReconsent=false; AWSALB=hSe9Dtqo8cPvWzIyv/lT0nhcCJ822BzrFDng1sT+fBBmde4CPOMbJJpCE3PESkURtsxxEGKsTwlnlN8ybLLed4pVYfE6tDiFKz9WD5fBYeydSBZw/k1tMkG+/2fa; AWSALBCORS=hSe9Dtqo8cPvWzIyv/lT0nhcCJ822BzrFDng1sT+fBBmde4CPOMbJJpCE3PESkURtsxxEGKsTwlnlN8ybLLed4pVYfE6tDiFKz9WD5fBYeydSBZw/k1tMkG+/2fa; dtCookie=v_4_srv_3_sn_2832183B98BD4E50DD4D6456885CECA3_perc_100000_ol_0_mul_1_app-3A86e062a5b6c28a86_1_rcs-3Acss_0
```

but when i try to execute the same url from .net app, it gives a 403 error. my .net code is as follows

```
public HttpResponseMessage SendRequestPostNew(string destinationMethod, string destinationURL,string requestContent,string TimeoutValue)
        {
            var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
            httpClientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };
            httpClientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (message, cert, chain, errors) => { return true; };
            HttpClient clientNew = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler);

            try
            {

                using (var newRequest = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod(destinationMethod), destinationURL))
                {
                    newRequest.Headers.Accept.Clear();
                    newRequest.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                    //newRequest.Content = new StringContent(requestContent, Encoding.UTF8, request.ContentType);
                    newRequest.Content = new StringContent(requestContent, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

                    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls13 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
                    
                    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback +=(sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => { return true; };
                    //System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;

                    client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Convert.ToInt32(TimeoutValue));

                    var response = clientNew.SendAsync(newRequest);
                    {
                        return response.Result;
                    }
                    
                }
            }catch(Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            finally
            {
                clientNew.Dispose();
            }

        }
```

403 ERROR

The request could not be satisfied.

Bad request. We can't connect to the server for this app or website at this time. There might be too much traffic or a configuration error. Try again later, or contact the app or website owner.

If you provide content to customers through CloudFront, you can find steps to troubleshoot and help prevent this error by reviewing the CloudFront documentation.

Generated by cloudfront (CloudFront) Request ID: EXUpjNsCEJfyHq_q0PobrhVpOr1e3EfbH8grxVhVTsz036MSbIrkmg==

Where could be the issue?

Comment: Usually things like this are lack of proper headers, lack of cookies or lack of javascript that does something after working out that a human is using the page, possibly in CF's case, all of them and more. We'll need more info to be able to advise; open the browser dev tools and look in the network tab to see what exactly your browser is sending/how, when it gets a good response, then we can work out what differences will arise when your C# talks to the API

Comment: @CaiusJard, i have added the dev tools output in the question

Comment: Well for a start there are a load more headers in the browser version than the c# version..

Comment: I'm having the same issue, has there been a solution for this yet?

Answer (score 0):

CloudFront might block the request if "user-agent" header is absent or doesn't make sense.
Possibly a few more headers are missing. Try to compare to set of headers:

- the ones sent by your browser
- the ones sent by your application

Answer (score 0):

Basically the solution was to add the `"User-Agent"` header to the request.

```cs
using var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, url);
request.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/119.0.0.0 Safari/537.36");
```

You can also try to provide `"Accept-Encoding"`, but then before reading the content you will need to unzip it. But it looks like the bare minimum requires adding `"User-Agent"` to headers.